# MySQL-запрос на две таблицы

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Всем привет. Хочу реализовать запрос на mysql, но не совсем все получается.

Имеются три таблицы таблицы: user (Пользователи), event (События пользователя), read (Кто и за чьими событиями следит).

`user {
id // Идентификатор записи и как ID для распознания пользователя
Дальше идут данные пользователя
...
}`

`event {
id //Идентификатор записи
idsend //Идентификатор пользователя, который отправил это событие (автор).
msg // Сам текст события
time // Время отправления
}`

`read {
kto // идентификатор пользователя, который подписался на другого человека с идентификатором в колонке "kogo"
kogo // Пользователь за которым следят пользователь с идентификатором из колонки "kto".
}`

Суть запроса - выводить на одной странице все события пользователей, на которых подписан. Принцип твиттера. Сам запрос реализовать получилось, но не получается сделать так, чтобы изначально выводились и свои события вместе с другими. В моем случае выводится только чисто те события, на которые подписан.

```
Стандартная переменная: $id - Мой идентификатор.
```

Запрос, который получился у меня:

```
SELECT c.* FROM event c, read s '. 'WHERE c.idsend = s.kogo AND s.kto = '.$id.' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

Пробовал добавить еще один AND c.idsend = '.$id.' - но безуспешно. Заранее спасибо за помощь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = 'SELECT c.* FROM event c, read s WHERE (c.idsend = s.kogo AND s.kto = '.$id.') OR (c.idsend = '.$id.') ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10';
```

А вообще чтобы такого не было - после создания события сразу подписывайтесь на него.

вариант 2

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM event AS e
JOIN user AS u ON (e.idsend=u.id)
LEFT JOIN read AS r ON (e.idsend=r.kogo)
WHERE (r.kogo=NULL AND e.idsend='.$id.') OR (r.kogo='.$id.')
';
```

По идее должно работать так. Выбирает все события + юзеров, их создавших, если (подписки нет и я создатель) либо (подписка на мое событие)

Comment: Запрос выводит теперь только мои события и ничьи больше. =(

А подписываться на себя не вариант вообщем, так как в моих подписчиках буду я сам.

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Как-то все странно работает. =(
Выводит теперь, опять же, мои события, но повторяя при этом каждое событие 4 раза! =( Но все же, спасибо. =) 
А возможно ли сделать из нескольких запросов? =)